# Wordpress db prepare

Tags: wpdb

I am not trying to use $wpdb->insert, but prepare.

Insert method will have one query string and an array which includes # of data which is not defined but will be defined for each query string keyword.

For example, "address.insert" query string defines a string of query with 3 variables when it process query such as owner_id, address_info, city.

Instead of using $owner_id, ... , $country at the $wpdb->prepare section, I am trying to pass an array holds all of variables listed in below.

Does anyone know if it is doable passing an array for prepare?
It wasn't working for me when I tried.

Works

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($this->queryArray[$selectQuery], $owner_id, $address1, $address2, $city, $zip, $country);
```

Trying to do

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($this->queryArray[$selectQuery], $inputArray);
```

Here's an example code.

```
public function Insert($selectQuery, $inputArray)
{
    try
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare($this->queryArray[$selectQuery], $owner_id, $address1, $address2, $city, $zip, $country);
        $result = $wpdb->query($sql);
        return $result;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Solved: This just works fine.

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($this->queryArray[$selectQuery], $inputArray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), 2nd parameter for the prepare() method:

> (int|string|array) The value to substitute into the placeholder. Many
>   values may be passed by simply passing more arguments in a
>   sprintf()-like fashion. **Alternatively the second argument can be an
>   array containing the values as in PHP's vsprintf() function.** Care must
>   be taken not to allow direct user input to this parameter, which would
>   enable array manipulation of any query with multiple placeholders.
>   Values must not already be SQL-escaped.

So you can directly pass your input array, as long as you have same number of "%s" placeholders in your query string as the array length.

Btw in your code above the `$owner_id, $address1, $address2, $city, $zip, $country` variables are undefined. Did you miss `extract($inputArray)` ?

Comment: Yes, it works! It wasn't working because there was a silly typo but giving me not much info about it. Thanks a lot @One Trick Pony. The array just work as I was trying to do, edited above.